# Java/LWJGL - cannot disable color clamping

Tags: java, lwjgl

**Solution below**

I'm trying to disable the clamping of colors, but it does not work. There are the same OpenGL calls, such as a comparable c++ program where they work. To disable the clamping I use the following code:

```
GL30.glClampColor(GL30.GL_CLAMP_READ_COLOR, GL11.GL_FALSE);
GL30.glClampColor(GL30.GL_CLAMP_VERTEX_COLOR, GL11.GL_FALSE);
GL30.glClampColor(GL30.GL_CLAMP_FRAGMENT_COLOR, GL11.GL_FALSE);
```

For a better understanding the full code below and also a test class. As you can see, there is a test in swap if the values are below zero. I think the buffer is a floating point buffer and also the clamping is disabled. So I have no clue why it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

**Canvas.java:**

```
package render;

import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.WritableRaster;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import org.lwjgl.BufferUtils;
import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL14;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL30;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Pbuffer;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.PixelFormat;
import org.lwjgl.util.glu.GLU;

public class Canvas {
    private final int m_width;
    private final int m_height;

    private Pbuffer m_buffer;
    private final FloatBuffer m_readBuffer;
    private final float[] m_data;
    private final FloatBuffer m_dataBuffer;

    public Canvas(final int width, final int height) {
        this.m_width = width;
        this.m_height = height;

        this.m_data = new float[this.m_width * this.m_height * 4];

        this.m_dataBuffer = FloatBuffer.wrap(this.m_data);
        this.m_readBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(this.m_data.length);
    }

    public void disable() {
        GL11.glPopClientAttrib();
        GL11.glPopAttrib();
    }

    public void disable2D() {
        GL11.glPopAttrib();
        GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
        GL11.glPopMatrix();
        GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
        GL11.glPopMatrix();
    }

    public void enable() {
        GL11.glPushClientAttrib(GL11.GL_CLIENT_VERTEX_ARRAY_BIT);
        GL11.glPushAttrib(GL11.GL_ALL_ATTRIB_BITS);

        GL30.glClampColor(GL30.GL_CLAMP_READ_COLOR, GL11.GL_FALSE);
        GL30.glClampColor(GL30.GL_CLAMP_VERTEX_COLOR, GL11.GL_FALSE);
        GL30.glClampColor(GL30.GL_CLAMP_FRAGMENT_COLOR, GL11.GL_FALSE);
    }

    public void enable2D(final int x, final int y, final int width,
            final int height) {
        GL11.glViewport(0, 0, this.m_width, this.m_height);

        GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
        GL11.glPushMatrix();
        GL11.glLoadIdentity();

        GLU.gluOrtho2D(0, this.m_width, 0, this.m_height);
        GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
        GL11.glPushMatrix();
        GL11.glLoadIdentity();

        GL11.glPushAttrib(GL11.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL11.GL_LIGHTING_BIT);
        GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_LIGHTING);
    }



    public void init() {
        try {
            if ((Pbuffer.getCapabilities() & Pbuffer.PBUFFER_SUPPORTED) == 0) {
                System.out.println("Canvas:: No PBuffer support!");
                System.exit(-1);
            }
            final PixelFormat pf = new PixelFormat();
            pf.withBitsPerPixel(32);
            pf.withFloatingPoint(true);
            this.m_buffer = new Pbuffer(this.m_width, this.m_height, pf, null);
            this.m_buffer.makeCurrent();
        } catch (final LWJGLException e) {
            System.err.println("Canvas:: Cannot create buffer!");
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        if (this.m_buffer.isBufferLost()) {
            this.m_buffer.destroy();
            System.err.println("Canvas:: Buffer was lost!");
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        System.out.printf("Canvas:: Created canvas (%d %d)\n", this.m_width,
                this.m_height);
    }

    public void swap() {
        synchronized (this.m_dataBuffer) {
            GL11.glReadPixels(0, 0, this.m_width, this.m_height, GL11.GL_RGBA,
                    GL11.GL_FLOAT, this.m_readBuffer);
            while (this.m_readBuffer.remaining() > 0) {
                final float t = this.m_readBuffer.get();
                if (t < 0) {
                    System.out.println(t);
                }
                this.m_dataBuffer.put(t);
            }
            this.m_dataBuffer.rewind();
            this.m_readBuffer.rewind();
        }
    }
}
```

**CanvasTest.java:**

```
package OpenGLTests;

import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;

import render.Canvas;

public class CanvasTest {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(100, 100);
        canvas.init();
        canvas.enable2D(0, 0, 100, 100);
        canvas.enable();

        GL11.glClearColor(-1, -1, -1, 1);

        GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL11.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        GL11.glColor4f(-1, -1, 1, 1);

        GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES);
        GL11.glVertex2f(0.f, 0.f);
        GL11.glVertex2f(100.f, 0.f);
        GL11.glVertex2f(50.f, 100.f);
        GL11.glEnd();

        canvas.swap();
        canvas.disable();
        canvas.disable2D();
        System.out.println("end");
    }
}
```

## Solution

Now I fixed the problem by using a FBO. I haven't known the difference between FBO and PBO (Pbuffer). But the PBO is apparently outdated and old, and don't support values, which are out of range. So you can see the initialization code of the fbo in the `init()` method below. Don't forget to bind the FBO when you use it.

```
    GL30.glBindFramebuffer(GL30.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, this.m_fbo);

    GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, this.m_color);
    GL11.glTexImage2D(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL30.GL_RGBA32F, this.m_width,
            this.m_height, 0, GL11.GL_RGBA, GL11.GL_FLOAT,
            (FloatBuffer) null);

    GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
            GL11.GL_NEAREST);
    GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,
            GL11.GL_NEAREST);
    GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,
            GL11.GL_CLAMP);
    GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,
            GL11.GL_CLAMP);

    GL30.glFramebufferTexture2D(GL30.GL_FRAMEBUFFER,
            GL30.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, this.m_color, 0);

    GL30.glBindFramebuffer(GL30.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

Comment: Do you actually have a floating point framebuffer?

Comment: @derhass I think so but i'm not sure about it but look above (Edit)

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
glClampColorARB(GL_CLAMP_READ_COLOR_ARB, GL_FALSE);
glClampColorARB(GL_CLAMP_VERTEX_COLOR_ARB, GL_FALSE);
glClampColorARB(GL_CLAMP_FRAGMENT_COLOR_ARB, GL_FALSE);
```

I'm also having problems with lwjgl/unclamped color/floating point framebuffers, but at least
for using glColor3f(2.0F, 1.0F, 1.0F) or such this seems to work (without framebuffers being
involved.) However, as far as I can tell you don't actually have a floating point framebuffer in there, so what this code will do is carry out the color multiplication and then clamp it to [0F, 1F]. This is desired because anything else will be undisplayable, *but* if you do end up creating an unclamped float framebuffer then you'll need to use GL_RGBA16F as the format and GL_FLOAT as the data type. I have a bit of a lack of understanding of this floating point
FBO stuff (as is shown by the fact I haven't figured it out myself) but nonetheless this has worked for me up to a point. I know some people only need the vertex color set to false, but I'm using all three calls to be sure it works. By the way, for lwjgl these can be found in org.lwjgl.opengl.ARBColorBufferFloat.

GL_FIXED_ONLY_ARB can be used in place of GL_FALSE. Just make sure that your buffer you're rendering to is floating point, since fixed-only will only unclamp if your buffer is floating point - integer (unsigned byte to be precise) is the default.

Just to reiterate once more, however, you won't be able to actually find the outside-of-bounds color results by reading the main display buffer - it'll be clamped, however you'll be able to see the results. As I've tried with those GL30 functions on my mac and it gave me errors to the tune of "unsupported", ARB works for me - but not with framebuffers. I don't understand why but for your purposes I think this will work.

If anyone knows I'm drastically wrong, please correct me.

EDIT: My problems with framebuffers were simply due to my own stupidity. HDR floating-point framebuffers can have HDR textures attached like so:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, hdrEnabled ? hdrFormat : GL_RGBA8, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, hdrEnabled ? hdrDataType : GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (java.nio.ByteBuffer) null);
```

There's a little snippet from my code, hdrFormat is an int set to GL_RGBA16F and hdrDataType is set to GL_HALF_FLOAT.